# Inserção dados em um ArrayList

Tags: java

Estou com um problema para implementar esse código, não consigo inserir os dados no Arraylist.

```
public class Principal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faltas faltas = new Faltas();
        faltas.inserirDados(111,3,5);

        for(int j=0;j<faltas.size();j++){
                System.out.println(faltas.get(j).getDados());
        }
  }  
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Faltas {
    int matricula;
    int mes;
    int dia;
    ArrayList<Faltas> faltas = new ArrayList();
    public Faltas(int matricula, int mes, int dia) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
    }
    public void inserirDados(int matricula,int mes, int dia) {
        faltas.addAll(matricula,mes,dia);
    }
    public String getDados(){
        return  "matricula: "+this.matricula+
                            "\nMes: "+this.mes+
                            "\nDia: "+this.dia+
                            "\n";
    }
}
```

Erro na compilação:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Faltas() is undefined
The method size() is undefined for the type Faltas
The method get(int) is undefined for the type Faltas

at TesteArray.Principal.main(Principal.java:9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro dar uma analisada nos seus conceitos de orientação objeto. A falta tem q ser criada como um objeto simples e a lista é uma união de várias faltas e fica fora da classe básica. Segue abaixo a forma ideal.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Principal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Falta> faltas = new ArrayList();
    faltas.add(new Falta(111,3,5));

    for(int j=0;j<faltas.size();j++){
      System.out.println(faltas.get(j).getDados());
    }
  }  
}

public class Falta {
  int matricula;
  int mes;
  int dia;

  public Falta(int matricula, int mes, int dia) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.dia = dia;
  }

  public String getDados(){
        return  "matricula: "+this.matricula+
                            "\nMes: "+this.mes+
                            "\nDia: "+this.dia+
                            "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá André Lins, na verdade esses dados são matricula 111, mes 3 , dia 5. Minha ideia é colocar esses dados no Arraylist pra depois trabalhar pegando as faltas do dia e mes  de um aluno referenciado por sua matricula (111).

Comment: @Bruno, veja como você pode fazer isso na minha resposta

Comment: André, eu consigo manter a main como faltas.InserirDados(111,3,5); ou seja sem o new.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Bruno!

Para resolver seu problema, substitua o método `ArrayList.addAll()` pelo `ArrayList.add()`, dessa forma

Substitua isso

```
 public void inserirDados(int matricula,int mes, int dia) {
        faltas.addAll(matricula,mes,dia);
    }
```

Por isso

```
 public void inserirDados(int matricula,int mes, int dia) {
        faltas.add(new Faltas(matricula,mes,dia));
    }
```

Porém aconselho você usar a classe `Faltas` para apenas representar a falta (os dados referentes à ela) sem atribuir à ela a responsabilidade de inserção na lista. Para isso, faça o seguinte

```
public class Falta {
    int matricula;
    int mes;
    int dia;

    public Falta() { }

    public Falta(int matricula, int mes, int dia) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public String getDados(){
        return  "matricula: "+this.matricula+
                "\nMes: "+this.mes+
                "\nDia: "+this.dia+
                "\n";
    }
}
```

Adicione os `getters` e `setters` à classe. Esses métodos acessam e salvam valores nos atributos da mesma  (deixei também o nome no singular). Agora você pode salvar cada falta separadamente numa lista

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Falta> faltas = new ArrayList<>();
                         faltas.add(new Falta(102939393, 3, 15));
                         faltas.add(new Falta(201801283, 1, 29));
                         faltas.add(new Falta(201938377, 12, 3));
                         faltas.add(new Falta(201938377, 12, 4));
                         faltas.add(new Falta(201938377, 12, 5));

        for (Falta f: faltas) {
            if (f.getMatricula() == 201938377) {
                String str = String.format("Faltou em %d/%d", f.getDia(), f.getMes());
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```